# Notepad++ merge all lines that do not begin with a date

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have  `.csv` file in Notepad++ that contains data like this:

```
1-6-2018,"(101)","","Sale",-862.96,,
"(Sale)",,837.96,
,"Diesel",12.000 Ltr,69.83/Ltr,837.96,
"Sales @ 5%",,23.80,
,"Polishing Cloth",1 Pcs,23.80/Pcs,23.80,
"CGST @ 2.5%",,0.60,
"SGST @ 2.5%",,0.60,
"(No. :16532)",
1-6-2018,"(149)","","Sale",-3212.18,,
"Sales(Sale)",,3212.18,
,"Diesel",46.000 Ltr,69.83/Ltr,3212.18,
"(No. :16533)",
// and many more
```

How can I use search and replace (or any other method) in Notepad++ to merge all lines that do not begin with a date, so the end result look like this?

```
1-6-2018,"(101)","","Sale",-862.96,,"(Sale)",,837.96,,"Diesel",12.000 Ltr,69.83/Ltr,837.96,"Sales @ 5%",,23.80,,"Polishing Cloth",1 Pcs,23.80/Pcs,23.80,"CGST @ 2.5%",,0.60,"SGST @ 2.5%",,0.60,"(No. :16532)",
1-6-2018,"(149)","","Sale",-3212.18,,"(Sale)",,3212.18,,"Diesel",46.000 Ltr,69.83/Ltr,3212.18,"(No. :16533)",
```

Each line that does not begin with a date is merged with the previous one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4})`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          : any kind of linebreak
(?!         : start negative look ahead, make sure we don't have after:
  \d{1,2}   : 1 or 2 digits
  -         : a dash
  \d{1,2}   : 1 or 2 digits
  -         : a dash
  \d{4}     : 4 digits
)           : end lookahead (ie. a date)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
1-6-2018,"(101)","","Sale",-862.96,,"(Sale)",,837.96,,"Diesel",12.000 Ltr,69.83/Ltr,837.96,"Sales @ 5%",,23.80,,"Polishing Cloth",1 Pcs,23.80/Pcs,23.80,"CGST @ 2.5%",,0.60,"SGST @ 2.5%",,0.60,"(No. :16532)",
1-6-2018,"(149)","","Sale",-3212.18,,"Sales(Sale)",,3212.18,,"Diesel",46.000 Ltr,69.83/Ltr,3212.18,"(No. :16533)",
```